# Numbering a specific occurence on both sides margins

Tags: numbering, margins, screenplay

[LaTeX]

Hello everyone !

I was wondering how I could obtain a numbering which would look like this :

[image]

So with the help of @Steven, I've manage to come up to this result :

[image]

The code I used to do this is :

```
\documentclass{screenplay}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{tabto,lipsum}
\newcounter{bangno}

\newcommand\bang{%
  \leavevmode%
  \stepcounter{bangno}%
  \tabto*{-.5in}\llap{\thebangno}\tabto{\TabPrevPos}%
  \tabto{\dimexpr\textwidth+.5in}\thebangno\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
}

\newcommand{\sce}{\MakeUppercase{scene }}
\newcommand{\se}[1]{\sce{#1}}

\begin{document}

rsonnages décident d'aller dans la forêt que s'achève la partie des Evénements. 

\bang\se{2}

Enfin, l'apocalypse met en scène la mort de tous les personnages à l'exception d'un seul, et du personnage suicidé plus tôt dans l'int

\bang\extslug[day]{hospital}
rsonnages décident d'aller dans la forêt que s'achève la partie des Evénements. 
Enfin, l'apocalypse met en scène la mort de tous les personnages à l'exception d'un seul, et du personnage suicidé plus tôt dans l'int

\end{document}
```

See, when I use my `\se{}`, the number goes at the right place.
But when I use `\extslug[]{}`, wherever I place the `\bang`, the number goes juste before or after...

The `\extslug[]{}`is defined this way :

```
\newcommand*{\placesep}{.~}
\newcommand{\slug}[3][]{%

\MakeUppercase{#2\placesep#3}%
\ifthenelse{\not\equal{#1}{}}
                {%
\slugspace\MakeUppercase{#1}\hspace{\fill}
                }{}
\nopagebreak 

}
\newcommand*{\exttext}{EXT}
\newcommand{\extslug}[2][]{\slug[#1]{\exttext}{#2}}
```

So if you have any idea, it's more than welcome !

Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the section commands to output the number twice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\z{zz z z z z z z z z z }

\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{%
\llap{\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%
\rlap{\hskip\textwidth\quad\csname the#1\endcsname}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Something}

\z\z\z\z\z\z

\section{Something Else}

\z\z\z\z\z\z



\end{document}
```

---

Or the same using the screenplay macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{screenplay}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{tabto,lipsum}
\newcounter{bangno}


\newcounter{zz}

\renewcommand{\extslug}[2][]{%
\refstepcounter{zz}%
 \slug[#1]{%
\mbox{}\llap{\thezz\quad}\rlap{\hskip\textwidth\thezz}%
\exttext}{#2}}

\newcommand{\sce}{\MakeUppercase{scene }}
\newcommand{\se}[1]{\sce{#1}}

\begin{document}

rsonnages décident d'aller dans la forêt que s'achève la partie des Evénements. 

\extslug[day]{hospital}
rsonnages décident d'aller dans la forêt que s'achève la partie des Evénements. 
Enfin, l'apocalypse met en scène la mort de tous les personnages à l'exception d'un seul, et du personnage suicidé plus tôt dans l'int


\extslug[day]{hospital}
rsonnages décident d'aller dans la forêt que s'achève la partie des Evénements. 
Enfin, l'apocalypse met en scène la mort de tous les personnages à l'exception d'un seul, et du personnage suicidé plus tôt dans l'int

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well I didn't know that we could do that with the \section{} thing but it feels like your code does apply only to the argument \section{}, and I wouldn't know how to adapt it to my argument \extslug[]{} ...
Thanks you very much anyway though ! :D

Comment: @Grek if you had supplied a small example document showing the markup you wanted to use, then answers would have used that markup, otherwise we just have to guess some markup looking at the image you show,

Comment: Well the fact is that I don't have any code corresponding to the image I've shown... But I agree that I wasn't that specific... I just edited my original post for a better understanding :)

Comment: @Grek screenplay example added

Comment: What if I would like to add more space between the numbers and the 'EXT-DAY' thing, especially in the left margin ? Would it be possible using what you did ?

Comment: yes I added `\quad` which is `\hspace{1em}`  so replace that by `\hspace{1cm}` or whatever actually I forgot to do the same on teh right, so `\hskip\textwidth` should be `\hskip\textwidth\hspace{1cm}` (or whatever) to match.

Comment: I replaced `\quad`by `\hspace{4em}`to move it at the right place to the left and I added `\hspace{1cm}` in the argument dealing with the right side to move the number to the good spot.
It worked fine ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

See **ADDENDUM**

The macro `\bang` will increment the counter, apply the number on both sides and pick up where you left off.  It uses the `tabto` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto,lipsum}
\newcounter{bangno}
\newcommand\bang{%
  \leavevmode%
  \stepcounter{bangno}%
  \tabto*{-.5in}\llap{\thebangno}\tabto{\TabPrevPos}%
  \tabto{\dimexpr\textwidth+.5in}\thebangno\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\bang\lipsum[2]
\bang\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**ADDENDUM**

Using the OP's updated information and MWE.  What was required was using `\noexpand\bang` inside either of the arguments to `\extslug` (note that `\protect\bang` also works).

```
\documentclass{screenplay}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{tabto,lipsum}
\newcounter{bangno}

\newcommand\bang{%
  \leavevmode%
  \stepcounter{bangno}%
  \tabto*{-.5in}\llap{\thebangno}\tabto{\TabPrevPos}%
  \tabto{\dimexpr\textwidth+.5in}\thebangno\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}%
}

\newcommand{\sce}{\MakeUppercase{scene }}
\newcommand{\se}[1]{\sce{#1}}

\begin{document}

rsonnages décident d'aller dans la forêt que s'achève la partie des Evénements. 

\bang\se{2}

Enfin, l'apocalypse met en scène la mort de tous les personnages à l'exception d'un seul, et du personnage suicidé plus tôt dans l'int

\extslug[day\noexpand\bang]{hospital}
rsonnages décident d'aller dans la forêt que s'achève la partie des Evénements. 
Enfin, l'apocalypse met en scène la mort de tous les personnages à l'exception d'un seul, et du personnage suicidé plus tôt dans l'int

\bang\se{2}

Enfin, l'apocalypse met en scène la mort de tous les personnages à l'exception d'un seul, et du personnage suicidé plus tôt dans l'int

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Woh ! It's been a huge help !

Thank you very much ! However, it does not solve my problem entirely, because when I use \bang in front of \se{}, like this '\bang\se{}', it makes the number at the right place and on the same line, which is great. I defined \se like this : '\newcommand{\sce}{\MakeUppercase{scene }}
\newcommand{\se}[1]{\sce{#1}}' Though, when I use \bang with \extslug[]{}, like this '\bang\extslug[]{}', the number appear but on the line just before... I don't know how to explain it so if you have an idea... ! Thank you anyway for your huge help :)
(idk how to insert img here)

Comment: @Grek Without know what exactly `\extslug` is, it is hard to say.  But try reversing the order, `\extslug[]{}\bang`.  Depending on what `\extslug` actually does, you may even be able to place `\bang` inside one of its arguments.

Comment: Well I did, that doesn't change anything.
Here's how the `\extslug` command is defined in the package :
`\newcommand{\slug}[3][]{%

\MakeUppercase{#2\placesep#3}%
\ifthenelse{\not\equal{#1}{}}
                {%
\slugspace\MakeUppercase{#1}\hspace{\fill}
                }{}
\nopagebreak 

}
\newcommand*{\exttext}{EXT}
\newcommand{\extslug}[2][]{\slug[#1]{\exttext}{#2}}`
Thanks again :)

Comment: @Grek And what is `\placesep`?

Comment: I guess it's this `\newcommand*{\placesep}{.~}`

Comment: @Grek Here is the importance of including a minimal, but fulling working example in your question.  Using the information you have provided, I have no problem getting the `\bang` to appear on the same line as `\extslut[]{}`.  So, obviously, there is something more to your problem, likely associated with the documentclass or the packages that are loaded.  You really need to post a minimum working example that shows the problem.

Comment: I'll comment my original post with some pictures and a minimal then.

Comment: @Grek You don't have to "comment" your post.  You can "edit" it!

Comment: Great idea ! I just did it :)

Comment: @Grek See my addendum  A little `\noexpand` did it.

Comment: Wow ! It worked ! That's great ! I don't really get how the `\noexpand`works, but it works.
Thank you again for everything :)

Comment: @Grek I  note that `\protect\bang` works equally well.  These commands prevent the expansion of the subsequent argument (in the case of `\protect`, it works for one layer of expansion).  This can be important if you need to prevent the `\bang` from immediately executing when TeX first digests it.  You can search this site for questions about `\protect` and so-called "moving arguments."